# Implementation of priority scheduler as subclass of doubly-linked list

Tags: c++, list, queue

I am working on implementation of a scheduler as a subclass of queue. My functions work fine, but as far as I know for the coursework purposes, sorting and antiblocking algorithm shall be called from Schedulers version of NodeDequeue.

When I put calls from that function code doesn't work and debugger says that, quicksort and antiblock functions can't access the parts of a code.

Is it possible to make program work and call sorting from NodeDequeue or do you have any other way to make it work?

```
class Node
{
public:

Node(int value, Node* nextptr = nullptr, Node* prevptr = nullptr, int     currentpriority = 0)
{
    this->value=value;
    next = nextptr;
    prev = prevptr;
    priority = currentpriority;

}

int getVal(void)
{
    return value;
}

Node* getNext(void)
{
    return next;
}

Node* getPrev(void)
{
    return prev;
}

void setVal(int value)
{
    this->value = value;
}

void setPrev(Node* prevptr)
{prev = prevptr; };

void setNext(Node* nextptr)
{
    next = nextptr;
}

int getPriority(void)
{
    return priority;
}

void setPriority(int priority)
{
    this->priority = priority;
}

private:
Node* next;
Node* prev;
int priority;
int value;
};

class Stack
{
public:
Stack(void) 
{
    top = nullptr;
}


~Stack(void)
{
    while (NodePop() != nullptr);
}

void Push(int value)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node(value,top);   
    top = tmp;
}

Node* NodePop(void)
{
    Node* tmp = top;
    if (top != nullptr) top = top->getNext();
    return tmp;
}

int Pop(void)
{
    Node* tmp = NodePop();
    int ret = 0;
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    { 
        ret = tmp->getVal();
    }

    else 
    {
        throw "Stack Empty";
    }
    delete tmp;
    return ret;
}

private:

Node* top;
};

class Queue
{
public:
Queue(void)
{
    back = front = nullptr;
}

~Queue(void)
{
    while (NodeDequeue() != nullptr);
}

void Enqueue(int i, int priority = 0)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node(i, back, nullptr, priority);
    back = tmp;
    if (front == nullptr) front = back;
    else
    {
        tmp = back->getNext();
        tmp->setPrev(back);
    }
}

int Dequeue(void)
{
    Node* tmp = NodeDequeue();
    int ret = 0;
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        ret = tmp->getVal();
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Queue Empty";
    }
    if (front == nullptr) back = front; // queue now empty
    delete tmp;
    return ret;
}

protected:

Node* back;
Node* front;

private:

virtual Node* NodeDequeue(void)
{
    Node* tmp = front;
    if (front != nullptr)
    {
        front = front->getPrev();
        if (front != nullptr) front->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    return tmp;
}
};


class Scheduler : public Queue
{

public:


private:

Node* NodeDequeue(void)
{
    Node* tmp = front;
    quicksort();
    antiBlock();
    if (front != nullptr)
    {
        front = front->getPrev();
        if (front != nullptr) front->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    return tmp;
}

int cycle = 0;

    void EnqueueFront(int i, int priority = 0)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node(i, nullptr, front, priority);
    front = tmp;
    if (back == nullptr) back = front;
    else
    {
        tmp = front->getPrev();
        tmp->setNext(front);
    }

}


Node* NodeDequeueBack(void)
{
    Node* tmp = back;
    if (back != nullptr)
    {
        back = back->getNext();
        if (back != nullptr) back->setPrev(nullptr);
    }
    return tmp;
}



int DequeueBack(void)
{
    Node* tmp = NodeDequeueBack();
    int ret = 0;
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        ret = tmp->getVal();
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Queue Empty";
    }
    if (back == nullptr) front = back; // queue now empty
    delete tmp;
    return ret;
}
void quicksort()
{
    Enqueue(0);
    EnqueueFront(0);
    partition(back, front);
    Dequeue();
    DequeueBack();
}

void partition(Node * left, Node * right)
{
    Node *p, *i, *j;
    p = left->getNext();
    i = p->getNext();
    if (i != right)
    {
        do
        {

            j = i;
            i = i->getNext();
            if (j->getPriority() < p->getPriority())
            {
                j->getPrev()->setNext(j->getNext());
                j->getNext()->setPrev(j->getPrev());
                j->setNext( p);

                j->setPrev( p->getPrev());
                p->setPrev( j);
                j->getPrev()->setNext( j);

            }
        } while (i != right);
        if (left->getNext() != p) partition(left, p);
        if (p->getNext() != right) partition(p, right);
    }
}
Node* split()
{

         Node *singleJump = back, *doubleJump = back;
        while (singleJump->getNext() && doubleJump->getNext()->getNext())
        {
            doubleJump = doubleJump->getNext()->getNext();
            singleJump = singleJump->getNext();
        }
        Node *temp = singleJump->getNext();
        singleJump->getNext()->setNext(nullptr);
        return temp;
}

void antiBlock()
{
    cycle++;
    if (cycle == 5)
    {
        Node* temp = split();
        while (temp != front)
        {
            if (temp->getPriority() < 10)

                temp->setPriority(temp->getPriority() + 1);

        }
        cycle = 0;
    }
}


};



int main()
{

    Scheduler* s= new Scheduler;
    s->Enqueue(1,5);
    s->Enqueue(2, 6);
    s->Enqueue(3, 1);
    s->Enqueue(4, 8);
    s->Enqueue(5, 9);
    s->Enqueue(6, 10);
    s->Enqueue(7, 6);
    s->Enqueue(8, 3);
    s->Enqueue(9, 2);
    s->Enqueue(10, 7);
    s->Enqueue(11, 4);
    s->Enqueue(12, 8);
    s->Enqueue(13, 3);
    s->Enqueue(14, 6);
    s->Enqueue(15, 2);
    s->Enqueue(16,7);
    //s->quicksort();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    cout<<  s->Dequeue();

    return 0;


};
```

Comment: Do you realize that your `quicksort` is private?

Comment: Yes, we are not supposed to code anything in public in scheduler as it is supposed to use public API of queue. When I moved quicksort to public problem stayed the same

Comment: If that's the case, then take advantage of the polymorphism.

Comment: What do you mean? NodeDequeue is virtual and if I get it right it shouldn't have problems using private functions, because It is part of scheduler aswell. The debugger says: Unable to read memory

Comment: So I put your code to run, and it result in a stack overflow. I appears that the call to `dequeue` in `quicksort` is causing a infinite recursion. And I could not replicate your problem.

Off topic: Your `new Scheduler` stands without corresponding `delete`.

Comment: Yes mate, I have just realised that the problem is that infinite recursion. Have you got any idea how change quicksort function and maintain the public API? Thanks for offtopic, main function is just for testing and we doesn't submit it anyway.